# UIPasteboard: pasting images from Safari

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, paste, uipasteboard

I'm currently working on an app that has a chat feature. As part of this feature, I want to enable pasting images from the clipboard in order to send them as a message.

I overrode `canPerformAction` to allow pasting when the pasteboard has any images.

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if UIPasteboard.general.hasImages {
        return true
    } else {
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

Then I overrode `paste` method to get the image from UIPasteboard and send the message.

```
override func paste(_ sender: Any?) {
    if let image = UIPasteboard.general.image {
        if let data = UIPasteboard.general.data(forPasteboardType: kUTTypeGIF as String) {
            sendImageMessage(data, imageName: "Clipboard image.\(image.fileType())")
        } else if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9) {
            sendImageMessage(data, imageName: "Clipboard image.\(image.fileType())")
        }
        return
    }
    super.paste(sender)
}
```

The code works fine if I copy an image from Photos, but when I tried pasting an image that I copied before on Safari what is pasted is the image URL.

Any idea bout how to fix that issue? I've made some research but I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: If you have the image URL, it seems like you'll need to download it and then use the image data that you receive. Have you tried downloading from the URL?

Comment: I see you're looking for Gif or JPEG data... how about PDF, PNG, SVG, etc.  What types is Safari putting on the pasteboard when the image is copied?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. The problem is `UIPasteboard.general.url` or `UIPasteboard.general.string` to get the URL always seem to be empty.

Comment: @ScottThompson actually I'm checking if the pasteboard contains a gif so I can handle it differently in order to keep the animation. If not I process any other image types in the same way.